# Navbar not sticking

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm relatively new to coding a website and don't have much experience on stack overflow. For some reason it seems my navbar doesn't want to stick. I've searched around but can't find any obvious issues. Thanks for the help!

**HTML**

```
<script>
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};
var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;


function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    navbar.classList.add("sticky")
  } else {
    navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
</script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="navbar" id="navbar">
  <a href="Contact.html">Contact</a>
  <a href="Passion.html">My Passions</a>
  <a href="About.html">About</a>
  <a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a>  
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.navbar {
    overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.navbar a{
  float: right;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.navbar a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.content {
  padding: 16px;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.sticky + .content {
  padding-top: 60px;
}
```

If there is anything else you need from me to help just let me know.

Comment: Make sure you have enough content on the page to actually scroll, and try `window.onscroll = myFunction;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this problem just leaving the class `sticky` in the `navbar`:

```js
//just to occupy space
var cad='<br>';
for(i=0;i<1000;i++){
  cad+="<p>Something</p>";
  
}

document.getElementById('content').textContent=cad;
```

```css
.navbar {
    overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.navbar a{
  float: right;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.navbar a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.content {
  padding: 16px;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.sticky + .content {
  padding-top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<body>

<div class="navbar sticky" id="navbar">
  <a href="Contact.html">Contact</a>
  <a href="Passion.html">My Passions</a>
  <a href="About.html">About</a>
  <a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a>  
</div>

<div id="content">
```

Comment: Thanks! Adding sticky in the navbar class seemed to fix the issue

Answer (score 2):

Just add this code to your .navbar class:

```
.navbar{
 position:fixed;
 }
```

And remove the .sticky class. This would suffice your needs.

Or if you want to save your time but have good looking navigation then you can visit this link and have a look at the example:
[Sticky Navigation Bar](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_navbar_fixed&stacked=h)

Answer (score 0):

As jmargolisvt said: make sure you have enough text under the navbar so you can scroll the page.

I have tried your code and it worked when I added a sufficient amount of text to the body.

Bonus hint: if you're using Visual Studio Code you can use "lorem*30" followed by the Tab key to add dummy text.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine. I'm just create a code snippet using your above code, but i'm unable to fine any issue. When user scroll it's perfectly adding **sticky** class in **navbar**.

May be you facing any other issue. Feel free to share your concern. Thank you

```js
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};
var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;


function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    navbar.classList.add("sticky")
  } else {
    navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

```css
#wrapper {
  height: 800px;
}

.navbar {
    overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.navbar a{
  float: right;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.navbar a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.content {
  padding: 16px;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.sticky + .content {
  padding-top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="navbar" id="navbar">
    <a href="Contact.html">Contact</a>
    <a href="Passion.html">My Passions</a>
    <a href="About.html">About</a>
    <a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a>  
  </div>
</div>
```